# Spring/Hibernate - Ignore Duplicate entry and continue to insert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm developing an application in Spring Boot environment and I'm using Hibernate to persist data. In this case:

- the transactions are managed by Spring automatically.
- my DAO module is marked with `@Transactional` and `@Repository` annotations.
- I use `EntityManager` called in DAO module with `@PersistenceContext` annotation.
- My DB is MySQL

I have one method in DAO module that inserts multiple records in a table:

```
@Override
public void insertMultiplePippo(List<Pippo> pl) throws PippoException{
    try {
        for (Pippo p : pl) {
            try {
                entityManager.persist(p);
            } catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
/*please enter HERE :) -->*/ logger.debug("Duplicate entry when retrieving history: keyname->" + p.getKeyName() + ", date->"
                        + p.getInsertionDate() + ", value->" + p.getContentValue());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error during insert multiple data ",e);
        throw new PippoException(PippoException.CodeError.dbError, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**I would like to have multiple inserts and, as there are duplicate entries, the program continues the remaining inserts.** 
Now, unfortunatelly, when there are a duplicate entry I have a MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException at runtime, and Hibernate stops the execution inside the "`for`" block and rollbacks.

I have no idea how ti handle this scenario.
Please, any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's better to post the stack of Exception

Answer (score -1):

If the number of records in the table is not that large, you may want to fetch all existing records out as a `Set<> existingPippos` and insert the result of `new HashSet<Pippo>(pl).removeAll(existingPippos)`, instead of catching for duplication.